# My avatar changed in SO but remain unchanged in chat?

Tags: support, chat, profile-picture

I want to change my Image in chat.stackoverflow.com. I changed it in SO, but it remains unchanged in chat.stackoverflow.com. why?

Note that it is changed in superuser, englishlearner and other communities, and the problem is for chat page only!

Comment: Caching, it's always caching...

Comment: @davidism It's not cashing! because I changed the browser and nothing changed!

Comment: @TheGoodUser server side caching, not client side caching.  You can't force SE's caches to be cleared.

Comment: @Servy I changed it twice, the first time it changed immidiately but the second not. It is still related to chaching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chat profiles automatically refresh from their parent profile occasionally, I believe at least once every 24 hours. Wait a while, and your profile picture should update on its own.

Comment: I changed it twice. first time it changed quickly in all the communities (including the chat profile), but the second time all changed but the chat profile remain the same. changing browser and the system doesn't helped, so I think it is not related to cash or something, right?

Comment: @TheGoodUser No, that's not right.  The fact that it updated quickly once and slowly another times does not mean that the information isn't cached.